# Multiple fbAsyncInit's?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

In my site I'm using asynchronous loading of the Facebook JS SDK. To actually set it up I use the standard FB.init inside of window.fbAsyncInit function.

However the issue is that in my site this function is on every single page. However when I'm in a subpage I can't directly add to the JS function due to the design of my site, I have to copy and paste the whole function and add my bits.

I don't think multiple fbAsyncInit's are possible, so whats the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this instead to check if you already have a fbAsyncInit and chain it toghether in that case:

```
var oldCB = window.fbAsyncInit;
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
    if(typeof oldCB === 'function'){
        oldCB();
    }
    //Do Something else here
 };
```

Comment: Oops, I forgot about this question. After more searching I did find that way of "extending" the function. Hopefully this will help someone else. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know if this is the "official" way of doing this? Or if Facebook suggests another method/has a solution for this? Seems like a pretty common thing to do unless you want to put _all_ your JS code in one place.

Comment: @powerbuoy I can't tell if there's an "official" way different than this one. But this is not a hack. This is a fairly common design pattern for javascript.

Comment: @EduardoCereto - ok thanks. Yea I know, I've done the same before when attaching events, thing is when I tried this yesterday it didn't seem to work and I find it strange that FB doesn't give us an easier way of doing it (something like `fbAsynInit.addFunc(function () {})` would be nice).

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the facebook api can call fbAsyncInit before your second fbAsyncInit has even started. This will fix that case:

```
        if (window.fbAsyncInit.hasRun === true) {
            setup(); // do something
        } else {
            var oldCB = window.fbAsyncInit;
            window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                if (typeof oldCB === 'function') {
                    oldCB();
                }
                setup(); // do something
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a "static" property in fbAsyncInit

Try below

```
if (window.fbAsyncInit && window.fbAsyncInit.hasRun) {
    // do sth
}
```

Comment: I don't think that would wait though until fbAsyncInit runs.